# Is it possile to create a Windows 7 USB installer using Windows 7 USB/DVD Download Tool from a Virtual Machine?

Tags: windows-7, usb, virtualbox

I want to download the Windows 7 professional ISO (x86), from Microsoft, and , I can do two things. Or buy a new burner , as mine doesn't work (I am trying to decide what dvd writer I could buy) or use a usb dongle to copy the iso to it , and install it via usb.

I want to install Windows 7 in a netbook that now has Debian, and in my pc.

So i am trying to find a way of Create a Windows 7 usb installation , to at least be able to install windows 7 in the netbook without a external dvd writer.

I know that with dd in linux you can copy a debian.iso to the usb , and then install debian with it (i've done it) using something like dd if=win7.iso of=/dev/sdb, but i don't know if this would work for windows 7 iso,and if dd will correctly copy the iso to the usb.

I remembered that Microsoft created a tool to copy the iso to the usb using windows.

I thought that I could install in my pc , virtual box , as I have VT and 8 GB ram in it, and download the iso from microsoft ,install windows 7 in the virtual machine , and then copy the iso inside the machine , donwload the iso tool, and atach a usb to the pc, connect it to the guest , and use the tool to copy the iso to the USB.

But i don't now if is possible to use a virtual machine to do this , or the virtualization could give problems with the usb, or something.

I have found some minutes ago this 
https://serverfault.com/questions/6714/how-to-make-a-windows-7-usb-flash-install-media-from-linux

Should the virtual machine method work ?

Answer (score 1):

To install the Windows USB/DVD Download Tool:

1. Click to open the Windows USB/DVD Download Tool page.
2. Click Download then Run.
3. Follow the steps in the setup dialogs. You'll have the option to specify where to install the Windows USB/DVD Download Tool.

You must be an administrator on the computer on which you are installing the Windows USB/DVD Download tool. It requires the Microsoft .NET Framework version 2.0 or higher.

System requirements

Windows XP SP2, Windows Vista, or Windows 7 (32-bit or 64-bit)

Pentium 233-megahertz (MHz) processor or faster (300MHz is recommended)

50MB of free space on your hard drive

DVD-R drive or 4GB removable USB drive

I hope this helps!
James Cutt

Answer (score 0):

I've used the method you described of using Microsoft's tool on a XP VM to build the Win7 ISO, copied to a USB key and booted on the desired machine for installation.